# Dual monitor with ATI Radeon HD 3870

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have got 12.04 on my Desktop machine. I have also two dell monitors 24" and 22". My graphics card is "04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc R680 [Radeon HD 3870 x2]". I have searched and tried proposed solutions here and none work. I also tried xrandr but it behaves strangely. With xrandr, I cannot get the resolution right and the Fluxbox bottom bar is in the extended monitor (22"). Is there an easy way to get the extended desktop working correctly with Radeon HD 3870?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix it:

monitor 1 (24",1920x1080):
monitor 2 (22",1680x1050):

info about the monitors:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3600 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DIN disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

Command that actually sets the monitor:

```
$ xrandr --auto --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080 
$ xrandr --auto --output DVI-1 --mode 1680x1050 --right-of DVI-0
```